# Nautilus Desktop don't use the right folder

Tags: desktop, gnome, xdgutils

I'm on an elementaryOS Luna system. Originally it doesn't has the desktop for files, so I modded it with nautilus desktop. All works. I want that nautilus uses the "/home/user/Desktop" - Folder as Desktop, but it shows the content of the folder "/home/user/" as the desktop!

I read that i need to configure the "~/.config/user-dirs.dirs" with:

> XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
>
> XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
>
> XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
>
> XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
>
> XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
>
> XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
>
> XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
>
> XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"

Then i restarted nautilus, but the Desktop still shows all folders of "/home/user/"

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you changed the Variable in dconf-editor `org-gnome-nautilus-preferences` the `desktop-is-home-dir`?
You need to click once, then click again so that it is not checked but in font size bold.

This should work.!